# Download file to stream instead of File

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm implementing an helper class to handle transfers from and to an AWS S3 storage from my web application.

In a first version of my class I was using directly a `AmazonS3Client` to handle upload and download, but now I discovered `TransferManager` and I'd like to refactor my code to use this.

The problem is that in my download method I return the stored file in form of `byte[]`. TransferManager instead has only methods that use `File` as download destination (for example [`download(GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest, File file)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#download(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest,%20java.io.File))).

My previous code was like this:

```
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key);
S3Object s3Object = amazonS3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
S3ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(objectInputStream);
```

Is there a way to use `TransferManager` the same way or should I simply continue using an `AmazonS3Client` instance?

Comment: Loading all bytes to memory is not a good practice. Consider returning the file and opening an input stream to read it, so your application won't crash when handling large files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TransferManager` uses `File` objects to support things like file locking when downloading pieces in parallel.  It's not possible to use an `OutputStream` directly.  If your requirements are simple, like downloading small files from S3 one at a time, stick with `getObject`.

Otherwise, you can create a temporary file with `File.createTempFile` and read the contents into a byte array when the download is done.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination. I'll use a temp file.